# SQL Encode string parameter so special characters work

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to be able to add a new SQL LOGIN and name it after a person email address.  For example "billg@example.com". When I pass this to the following stored procedure I get an error (error follows procedure).

The stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Forms].[AddLogin]
    @Email nvarchar(2048),
    @TenantPassword nvarchar(2048)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC('CREATE LOGIN ' + @Email + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @TenantPassword + ''', DEFAULT_DATABASE = DunderMifflin')
END
```

The Error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

I'm sure all I need to do is encode the parameter somehow. Any help? If I add a user via the SQL Manager wizard I can specify email addresses so I know that it is a valid Login name.

Comment: Obligatory injection warning: Please don't pass the user's password directly into this routine!! The user could enter a password of ');DROP DATABASE DunderMifflin;--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to surround it with square brackets, [as detailed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163523.aspx):

```
EXEC('CREATE LOGIN [' + @Email + '] WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @TenantPassword + ''', DEFAULT_DATABASE = DunderMifflin')
```

Comment: +1 Nice catch.  This may still fail when your password is not complex enough, so you might want to provide a return value!

Comment: Note this will fail when there is an apostrophe in the password!

Comment: Assuming he hadn't already escaped it, yes. That's outside the scope of his question, but the link in my answer goes over some techniques for avoiding that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory injection warning: 
Whatever you do, please don't pass the user's password directly into this routine!! What if the user entered a password of

```
bill');DROP DATABASE DunderMifflin;--
```

and then you are basically executing the statement:

```
CREATE LOGIN billg@microsoft.com WITH PASSWORD = 'bill');
DROP DATABASE DunderMifflin;
-- ''', DEFAULT_DATABASE = DunderMifflin')
```

and that's not good.

Comment: Totally agree and am aware of this problem.  So what do you suggest to secure it?

Comment: Actually looks like there are lots of suggestions in the link provided above by Chad.

Comment: yes, Chad's link does contain some good suggestions. just wanted to bring this vulnerability to the forefront if you weren't already aware of the risk.